# How to get past 30 days data from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am able to get one item from my table using ExpressionAttribute and a particular id. How can I get a list of items from the past 30 days?

An equivalent SQL statment would look like this:

`select * from tablename datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

[image]

Below is the code I have tried:

```
$sevenDaysAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('30 days')); 
echo $response = $dynamodb->query([ 'TableName' => 'notifications', 
                                    'KeyConditionExpression' => 'id = :id and date_time >= :datess', 
                                    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [ 
                                       ':id' => ['S' => '350'],
                                       ':datess' => ['S' => $sevenDaysAgo] ], 
                                    'ProjectionExpression' => 'id',
                                    'ConsistentRead' => true ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your table has a partition key called `id` and a sort (also called a range) key called `date_time` your query won't work the way you wrote it.

With DynanoDB, unlike a relational database, you can only query on partition key and sort key.

If you need to query based on an attribute that is not a sort or partition key your options are:

1. scan with filter - this works well when you expect the query to be retrieving the majority of the records in the table
2. create a secondary index that includes the attributes you're interested in querying on and query using the index